# Parse model with react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

[react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) provides `useLoader` to load models. The [examples](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/loading-models) show how to load models from a path/url. I've saved the binary representation of my model in the IndexDB of the browser.

I added this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gltfloader-forked-tye0f4?file=/src/App.js). It shows how the models are loaded via path/URL (like described in the docs). Also it shows how I need to read the binary from the `localStorage` into `binaryFromLocalStorage`.

How would I load/parse `binaryFromLocalStorage` with react-three-fiber?

Comment: show your codes

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial thanks for you reply. I added a sandbox. I hope it makes clear what I try to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for asking this!! This question/answer pair are exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage can only store strings.

So,

```
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem("file", event.target.result);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

To read

```
dataURItoBlob(localStorage.getItem("file")) // Blob
```

Saving binary to localStorage can be very unstable because localStorage is only 5MB, and different browsers have different limits.

You may want to use indexDB instead.

You can choose to use localForage, which provides a API interface to localStorage

Comment: You sir, are a hero!